# is Grails 2.1 supports to create .war file with Maven build

Tags: grails, maven-2, maven-plugin, grails-plugin

**is Grails 2.1 supports to create .war file with Maven build?**

Last week, i tried two days for that with grails 2.04 application. Even i was not able to succeed. Now, I am trying with Grails 2.1.X(exact 2.1.4). Now, i can do or not, i am not sure.

I did not find any documentation for that in the Grails official Documentation page. Even I am not able find anywhere else also.

Comment: did you try `mvn grails:package`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try *mvn package*.

Things work fine in Grails 2.1.1 that's for sure, can't confirm for any version lower than 2.1.x.

I uploaded a very basic Maven-Grails integration tutorial here: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tqGN61hiciE

Maybe the above link can help you validate your configuration at least.

Comment: thanks you very much my dear friend, have a wonderful day.... You solved my problem.